# How to split the column values after a certain number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
 ID      HoursWorked     TotalHours  
 23          1               1         
 23          1               2          
 23          1               3        
 23         0.5             3.5       
 23          1              4.5       
 23          1              5.5       
 23          1              6.5       
 23          1              7.5       
 23          1              8.5        
 61          1               1
 61          1               2
```

What I want to do is if the total hours hits 8 hours, I want to split that row (e.g. 8.5 in the sample data above) so that an employee always has the total hours of 8. If someone works over 8 hours it should continue after hitting 8 in the totalhours column. For example, I want something like this as my final result.

```
 ID      HoursWorked     TotalHours  
 23          1               1         
 23          1               2          
 23          1               3        
 23         0.5             3.5       
 23          1              4.5       
 23          1              5.5       
 23          1              6.5       
 23          1              7.5       
 23          0.5             8   *
 23          0.5            8.5  *
 61          1               1
 61          1               2
```

As you can see the row which originally had 8.5 for its totalhours got broken down into two different rows.

I couldn't think of any way to do this in SQL Server. I'd appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Ordering column is missing. Right now your data satisfy the condition. Just `order by ID, HoursWorked DESC`

Answer (score 0):

see if this works.

```
select ID,HoursWorked,TotalHours from table_name where TotalHours <=8
union
select ID,(HoursWorked-(TotalHours-8) as HoursWorked ,8 as TotalHours from table_name where TotalHours >8
union
select ID,(TotalHours-8) as HoursWorked ,TotalHours from table_name where TotalHours >8
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems rather complicated.  This approach takes all the rows before 8 hours.  It then finds the row that first passes 8 hours and splits that one as needed:

```
select id, hoursworked, totalhours
from t
where totalhours <= 8
union all
select t.id, v.hoursworked, v.totalhours
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by totalhours) as seqnum
      from t
      where totalhours > 8
     ) t cross apply
     (values (case when seqnum = 1 then totalhours - 8 end,
              case when seqnum = 1 then 8 end
              ),
             (case when seqnum = 1 and totalhours >= 8 then totalhours - 8 else hoursworked end,
              totalhours
             )
     ) v(hoursworked, totalhours)
where v.hoursworked > 0
order by id, totalhours;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c00803f34898b8b16d2d8e8683d49e22) is a db<>fiddle.